# Digital Bananas

Tags: lateral-thinking

Homer is taking a joy ride on the highway when he is pulled over by officer Mickey. "Do you know how fast you were going?" the officer asks condescendingly. Homer replies uneasily, "I may have been going a little fast, maybe 74 miles per hour...".  The officer sighs, "101 miles per hour, actually. You are aware that the speed limit is 70, yes?" Homer nods. "Well I'll let you off with a warning this time," continues the officer, putting away his notebook. "Next time, I'm going to have to ticket you."

**Why did the officer let Homer off with only a warning?**

Small hint:

> The [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag would be appropriate for this question.

Big hint:

> *"When this baby hits 130 miles per hour, you're gonna see some serious sh%&..."*

Comment: vulgar, as in hint 3, is usually prohibited. please consider deleting it since this is supposed to be a safe-for-children site. thank you for your cooperation

Comment: @Omega The quote is from a PG-rated film, so it seemed fair game.

Comment: Aha, that seems much more appropriate. Thanks for your cooperation!

Answer (score 10):

Building on Arnaud's answer and the comments to his answer

> Homer was running only $9_{(10)}$ mph above the speed limit so officer Mickey let him go.
>  The speed limit was $70_{(8)}$ (or $56_{(10)}$) while Homer was going $101_{(8)}$ (or $65_{(10)}$).

The explanation for the title

> and the base of their numbering system is that in Mickey and Homer's world, everyone has 8 **banana-looking digits** on their two hands.

Comment: On the right track. The title explanation is close but not quite correct. The missing piece is related to why you shouldn't need the spoilers.

Comment: @MooseBoys So, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rKSvlcAcmc) doesn't explain the 8 vs the 10?  It seems like that is what greysaff was implying.  Edit: Oh I just read the comment on the other answer.  I guess the "bananas" part is what is missing.

Comment: A clue for the 8 fingers is that both Mickey Mouse and Homer Simpson have 4 fingers in each hand

Answer (score 9):

Given the hint,

> which is an obvious reference to the first Back to the future movie, except that 88 has been replaced with 130, we can deduce that the implied  base is not 10 for all numbers. Indeed, $$\color{red}{88_{(10)}}=8\times 10+8\times 1=\color{red}{130_{(8)}}=1\times 8^2+3\times 8+0\times 1$$
>
>  In general, a base $8$ number looks smaller when turned into a base $10$ number. In particular, $$101_{(8)}=65_{(10)}$$ which is less than the $70$ limit.

However,

> This is only a partial answer since it doesn't explain how to get the number $8$ without the hint (hints are not supposed to be *necessary* to solve a puzzle), and it doesn't imply why the officer would need to fine the driver next time, since $65$ would still be less than $70$.

Comment: On the right track. The hints are not necessary, though I did consider adding the 'knowledge' tag at one point.

Comment: The officer says $70_8=56$, so Homer is still speeding.

Comment: Two hands have 10 fingers.

Comment: Homer Simpson and Mickey Mouse have fingers too. Not sure where the bananas thing plays into it.

Comment: Re hints being necessary: This answer was my first idea without even seeing the hint, just from the fact that $101$ is apparently close to $70$.

Comment: By the way, in octal $74$ and $101$ are much closer, than in decimal: $101_8-74_8=5_8(=5_{10})$, while $101_{10}-74_{10}=27_{10}$. It's much more likely to error by 5 mph, than by 27 mph.

Comment: @JiK I actually had the idea of changing the base without seeing the hints as well, but it's still made up and doesn't explain really why you should do that. Greysaff's idea in their answer is that Mickey and Homer are cartoon characters and have 8 fingers, therefore use base 8, but apparently that's not the whole story (according to the comments by the OP).

Comment: @Arnaud I think you're misinterpreting my comment on Greysaff's answer. The fact that Mickey and Homer have 8 fingers, combined with the otherwise unusual exchange between the two parties, is what leads to the conclusion to use base 8. The reasoning for the title is also related to knowledge of the named characters.

Comment: A quote from Walt Disney is rot13(Hfvat svir svatref jbhyq unir znqr Zvpxrl’f unaqf ybbx yvxr n ohapu bs onananf)

Comment: @Bananenkopp is this anecdote somewhat related to your nick?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No, unfortunately not. But I thought I should post it 'cause of my nick (and I think it is the missing link to the title)

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at the same answer as greysaff after the two hints; here's my take on the title meaning:

> A banana bunch is often referred to as a "hand", while individual bananas are referred to as "fingers". Fingers are also "digits" so the title itself is a hint to consider that the two characters only have 8 fingers.

Comment: Digits has two connections to the problem, one of which you've identified. Your bananas connection is not the one I was thinking of.